# Eigenvectors of Commutative Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $S,T : V \rightarrow V$ are linear maps of finite dimensional vector space over field $K$.Suppose $S$ and $T$ commute, I want to show for any $a\in K$, then $aI-S$ maps eigenvectors of $T$ onto itself. I have proved that if $v$ is eigenvector of $T$, then $Sv$ also so $av-Sv$ is eigenvector of $T$ with the same eigenvalue as $v$. But how to prove the map is surjective?

Comment: There is some missing hypothesis. If $S=aI$ then $S$ commutes with any $T$ but $(aI-S)$ maps every eigen vector of $T$ to $0$.

Comment: If $(aI-S)$ is invertible, then the conclusion holds.

Comment: @geetha290krm that's what I think, but tge problem does not give any extra condition

Comment: Well, I have given a  clear counter-example, so the question is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example, $T=S=I$, $a=1$ shows that surjectivity may fail.

Let us prove surjectivty assuming that $aI-S$ is invertible. Suppose $Tv=\lambda v$, $v \neq 0$. Let $w=(aI-S)^{-1} v$. Then $ w \neq 0$ and $(aI-S)w=v$. Let us show that $w$ is an eigen vector of $T$ Since $T$ and $S$ commute the same is true of $T$ and $(aI-S)^{-1}$. Hence, $Tw=T(aI-S)^{-1} v=(aI-S)^{-1} Tv=\lambda (aI-S)^{-1}v =\lambda w$.

Even the part you claim to have proved requires invertibilty of $(aI-S)$. If $Tv=\lambda v, v\neq 0$ then it is true that $T[(aI-S) v]=\lambda (aI-S)v$ but this does not prove that $(aI-S)v$ is an eigen vector. Eigen vectors have to be non-zero and $(aI-S)v$ may be $0$.

Comment: What if $aI-S$ is not identically zero but also not invertible?

Comment: Even the part you claim to have proved requires invertibilty of $(aI-S)$. If $Tv=\lambda v, v\neq 0$ then it is true that $T[(aI-S) v]=\lambda (aI-S)$ but this does not prove that $(aI-S)v$ is an eigen vector. Eigen vectors have to be non-zero and $(aI-S)v$ may be $0$.  @LaurencePW

Comment: Saying that $(aI-S) v\neq 0$ whenever $v \neq 0$ is equivalent to invertibility of $aI-S$. @LaurencePW

Comment: Thank you for the clarity.